# Powershell -match and weird results

Tags: powershell, match

I am having an issue with the `-match` feature in a conditional statement in powershell.

Say I have 3 files:

Test.dll  (this dll has the `[TestClass]` word in it)

Test1. dll (this dll has the `TestClass` without the brackets)

Test2. dll (this dll doesn't have it at all)

I am searching for the files that have only `[TestClass]`

If I use the following code, both Test.dll and Test1.dll work in this condition: (by the way, each `$_` is a dll)

```
   if ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -match "TestClass")
   {
     $ProjectTestContainers += $_
     Write-Host $ProjectTestContainers
   }
```

which it should, but that's not what I want. I only want the files that contain `[TestClass]`  So I tried this

```
if ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -match "`[TestClass`]")
{
   $ProjectTestContainers += $_
   Write-Host $ProjectTestContainers
}
```

This works for all conditions, Test.dll, Test1.dll and Test2.dll, which it shouldn't.  It should only give me Test.dll because it is the only one that contains `[TestClass]`

Any ideas?  Let me know if you need more from me.

Comment: Aren't `dll`s compiled? How are you going to match a string if the file is binary?

Comment: a lot of the code was pre-written, but somehow it is searching dlls.  It kind of works though because it is finding 'TestClass' in the first example.  But it's pulling in ANY 'TestClass', not just '[TestClass]'.  I really am assuming that somehow it can read text in a dll.

Comment: I think it might be a bigger fix than I thought. The person who originally wrote this is reading from dlls, which is weird to begin with. It is somehow finding matches in some cases though, which is weird. May be a fluke because it shouldn't work like that with dlls. This is pure ugliness. So arco444, you may be right.  I will probably have to rewrite this code.

Answer (score 2):

The `-match` operator is doing a regular expression comparison against your 'TestClass' string, so the backtick (`) character is not the correct escape character for regular expression patterns. You are correct in thinking that the bracket characters need to be escaped, since those are special characters in a regular expression pattern. Because we're dealing with regex, the correct escape character is '\'; try this instead:

```
if ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -match "\[TestClass\]")
```

Comment: I think I tried this as well and it didn't work.  But let me try again.

Comment: Yeah.  This one doesn't find `[TestClass]` anywhere.  It should find it in Test.dll.  The condition is completely skipped when using it.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you:
PS C:\Windows\system32> '[TestClass]' -match "\\[TestClass\\]"

True

Comment: yeah.  It's a weird situation.

Comment: You could also just switch to the -like operator, if the regular expression syntax is giving you trouble: 'TestClass' -like "\*[TestClass]\*"  True

Comment: using the -like "[TestClass]"  gives me the same results as above

Comment: sorry, check my edit -- the formatting here hid the asterisks; put asterisks on either side of '[TestClass]' when using -like.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this variant..more generic:

```
$m = '[TestClass]'
if ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_) -match [regex]::escape($m))
```

Comment: Ah; good point. Using [regex]::esape shows that the closing square bracket does NOT need to be escaped. So "\\[TestClass]" should do it.

Comment: this didn't work.  I think it might be a bigger fix than I thought.  The person who originally wrote this is reading from dlls, which is weird to begin with.  It is somehow finding matches in some cases though, which is weird.  May be a fluke because it shouldn't work like that with dlls. This is pure ugliness.

Comment: I was wondering about the .dll extensions; maybe strings.exe from Sysinternals would help here? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx